# Ignore index of a letter if I use it

Tags: java, arrays, indexof

I'm working on key columnar transposition cipher,

```
  for(int i = 0; i < column; i++){
    position = keyWord.indexOf(sorted_key[i]); // Here's the problem
       for(int j = 0; j < row; j++){
        matrix[j][position] = cipher_array[count];
        count++; }}
```

Keyword is:

> analyst

#### sorted_key is:

> {a, a, l, n, s, t, y}

When I tried to print the variable position:

> 0 0 3 1 5 6 4

But I'm supposed to get this:

> 0 2 3 1 5 6 4

The problem occurs when I have a duplicated letter in the key. 'a' in this example, it always sees the first index of it's occurrence even if there's a second or third occurrence of it. How could this be fixed?

Comment: Is it possibe that you can replace the character with some other value like '-1' or something when it's position had been noted??

Comment: According to Java Doc - `indexOf(String str) - 
Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character.`

Comment: @Shadow Yes but how can I do it? declaring another array?

Comment: @vinS Oh no! How can I achieve what I want using something other than indexof?

Comment: There are number of ways. You can try with `BitSet` to keep a track of visited index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a `Map` that holds the last index for each character:

```
Map<Character,Integer> indices = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
    // get the previous position of sorted_key[i] (or -1 is there is no previous position)
    int last = indices.computeIfAbsent(sorted_key[i],c->-1);
    // search for the next position of sorted_key[i]
    position = keyWord.indexOf(sorted_key[i],last+1);
    // store the next position in the map
    indices.put(sorted_key[i],position);
    for(int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
        matrix[j][position] = cipher_array[count];
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much! I've been trying to solve if for 2 days now!! Thank you again